# Why doesn't document.field_name.focus() execute?

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I found some code from 2011 that goes like this:

```
<textarea cols="20" rows="1" name="field_name" id="field_name">
</textarea>
<script>
    document.field_name.focus();
</script>
```

Code throws an error:

```
TypeError: document.field_name is undefined
```

I assume that back then code worked.  Why doesn't it work now (2016)? 
[At least not on the latest version of Mozilla Firefox]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a form as a container, i guess since the past (until now) you have to encapsulate the form data into a form to access directly the field name from document scope, take a look:

```js
document.form.field_name.focus();
```

```html
<form name="form">
  <textarea cols="20" rows="1" name="field_name" id="field_name" value="">
  </textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: interesting, thanks. encapsulating it into a form does work.

Comment: Yeah, thats a DOM form data handling rule, but you can use something like document.getElementByID('MyID') for example. This way you don't need any hierarchy to get the data. Another way is to get elements by their tags names (getElementsByTagName), so you need to loop between the nodes and build your own selection rule. Look: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp

Answer (score 1):

You may select the input using `document.getElementById`, like this:

```
<textarea cols="20" rows="1" name="field_name" id="field_name">
</textarea>
<script>
 document.getElementById('field_name').focus();
</script>
```